# How to disable Y-axis movement in the Bullet physics engine

Tags: c++, bullet-physics

I want to create an object than only moves along the the X and Z axes, while keeping the Y-axis disabled (it's like movement in 2D, and the object wont fall down).

I'm currently using a 6 dof constraint to restrict movement in the Y-axis, but it's not working:

```c
btRigidBody* zeroBody = new btRigidBody(0, NULL, NULL); // Create the body that we attach things to
btRigidBody* robot = mCarChassis->getBulletRigidBody();

btGeneric6DofConstraint* constrict = new btGeneric6DofConstraint(*robot, *zeroBody, btTransform::getIdentity(), btTransform::getIdentity(), false);

constrict->setLinearLowerLimit( btVector3( 1, 1, 1));
constrict->setLinearUpperLimit( btVector3(-1, 1,-1));

constrict->setAngularLowerLimit( btVector3( 1,  1,  1) );
constrict->setAngularUpperLimit( btVector3(-1, -1, -1) );

mBulletWorld->getBulletDynamicsWorld()->addConstraint(constrict);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://bulletphysics.org/Bullet/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?p=12113&sid=57b2b4c3ef51ca26decd572b4f15bb94#p12113, perhaps also set the Lower/Upper limits for the Y-axis to 0, instead of 1.

Answer (score 24):

The preferred way to achieve this in Bullet is to set the *linear factor* and possibly the *angular factor* for the body in question. This method is presented as a [Code Snippet](http://www.bulletphysics.org/mediawiki-1.5.8/index.php/Code_Snippets#I_want_to_constrain_an_object_to_two_dimensional_movement.2C_skipping_one_of_the_cardinal_axes) at the Bullet Wiki page.

In order to allow movement along only the Y-axis, you would use something like this:

```
body->setLinearFactor(btVector3(0,1,0));
```

If you additionally wish to disable rotation around any particular axis, you use the same procedure, but using the `setAngularFactor` function instead.

In [this simple example video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q0oRzFfEPTw) I have used the following two calls in order to disable movement along the Y-axis and to allow rotation around only the Y-axis. This effectively forces the body to remain in the XZ-plane in which it was initially created.

```
body->setLinearFactor(btVector3(1,0,1));
body->setAngularFactor(btVector3(0,1,0));
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to create a physics tick callback. This will be called every time bullet ticks internally. In this call back you can set the Y velocity to 0, effectively disabling Y movement. It would look something like this:

```
void myTickCallback(const btDynamicsWorld *world, btScalar timeStep) {
    //robotBody is the btRigidBody you want to constrain the movement of
    btVector3 velocity = robotBody->getLinearVelocity();
    robotBody->setLinearVelocity(velocity.x, 0, velocity.z);
}
```

You can read more about [simulation tick callbacks here](http://bulletphysics.org/mediawiki-1.5.8/index.php/Simulation_Tick_Callbacks).

Comment: Thank you! This is a great answer, since it also applies to the java port of JBullet as well (unlike the other answer).